# how to get record date wise descending and then give record which has no date- in sql

Tags: mysql

i have a table named attendance_master 
i have records like below:

### attendant_id |  inout_time            | name

```
    1            |    NULL                | n1  
    2            |    NULL                | n2 
    3            |    2015-05-18 10:10:00 | n3 
    4            |    2015-05-19 10:05:00 | n4
    5            |    2015-05-18 10:07:00 | n5
    6            |    2015-05-18 12:03:00 | n6
```

now i want result like below:

### attendant_id |  inout_time            | name

```
    4            |    2015-05-19 10:05:00 | n4
    6            |    2015-05-18 12:03:00 | n6
    3            |    2015-05-18 10:10:00 | n3 
    5            |    2015-05-18 10:07:00 | n5
    1            |    NULL                | n1  
    2            |    NULL                | n2
```

my current query and result is like below:

```
  select * from attendance_master order by inout_time DESC
```

Note: i dont want to use union.

### attendant_id |  inout_time            | name

```
    1            |    NULL                | n1  
    2            |    NULL                | n2 
    4            |    2015-05-19 10:05:00 | n4
    6            |    2015-05-18 12:03:00 | n6
    3            |    2015-05-18 10:10:00 | n3 
    5            |    2015-05-18 10:07:00 | n5
```

Comment: Thats weird `order by desc` should take the null at the end, what is the datatype of  `inout_time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by multiple conditions, using the same field:

```
order by inout_time is null, inout_time desc
```

that'd put the "null" fields first, then sort everything else in descending order.

Comment: should be order by inout_time desc , inout_time is null.  but its ok ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from attendance_master order by inout_time DESC, ISNULL(inout_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` clause will help you here:

```
SELECT * FROM attendance_master
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN inout_time is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    inout_time DESC
```